# C# Strange WPF Combobox Behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have simple window.
This is what happens when I click ComboBox:
[image: Screenshot]
List appears in upper left corner of screen instead of under Combobox.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfPortOfTestingCamera.VideoSettings"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Video Settings" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ResizeMode="NoResize" ShowInTaskbar="False" mc:Ignorable="d" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" d:DesignHeight="167">
    <StackPanel Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <GroupBox Header="Settings" Name="groupBox1">
            <Grid Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="175*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Content="Resolution:" Height="28" Name="label1" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Framerate:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="label2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1" />
                <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" SelectionChanged="comboBox1_SelectionChanged" />
                <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" Name="comboBox2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="150" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="comboBox2_SelectionChanged" />
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
        <Label Name="labelSelectedSize" Content="Size @ FPS" />
        <Button Name="button1" Content="Apply" Click="button1_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: It could be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998024/wpf-combobox-dropdown-part-appears-in-the-wrong-place

Comment: Works ok for me. What do you have in the code behind?

Comment: @Andrei Pana
It happened when I opened this window in the Loaded Event from another. I realy need fix for that.

Comment: Instead of opening it directly in the `Loaded` event, just queue another message on the `Dispatcher` to open it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of opening it directly in the Loaded event, just queue another message on the Dispatcher to open it.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into exactly this and just posted an example at [WPF ComboBox DropDown part appears in the wrong place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998024/wpf-combobox-dropdown-part-appears-in-the-wrong-place?lq=1) which worked for me.  The interested reader can go there to peruse my commentary, but here's the snippet (NOTE: WindoBaseLoadedHandler is the "Loaded=" handler specified in the XAML):

```
protected void WindowBaseLoadedHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
```

...non-essential lines of code removed...

```
    if (DataContext != null)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(() =>
        {
            this.IsEnabled = false;

            LoginDlg loginDlg = new LoginDlg();
            loginDlg.ShowDialog();

            if (!loginDlg.Success)
            {
                /*-----------------------------------
                 * Log on failed -- terminate app...
                 *----------------------------------*/
                ...termination logic removed...
            }

            this.IsEnabled = true;
        }));
    }
```