# WPF application unable to handle remote desktop resolution change

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, c#-4.0

I'm working on a .NET 4 WPF application, and just the other day, came across a very peculiar bug. I have three Windows 7 Pro machines involved: laptop (1366x768), desktop (1680x1050, multi-monitor), and the remote machine (resolution unknown). Our application is installed on the remote machine.

Consider the following events: I remote desktop into the remote machine from my laptop, start our application, and launch a particular feature (an mdi child) within the application. If I connect to the same remote session from my desktop (thus closing the session on my laptop), this feature within my application becomes completely unusable. By unusable, I mean combo box drop downs are showing in the top/left corner (much like what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677701/c-sharp-strange-wpf-combobox-behavior)), other controls aren't laid out correctly, and some controls don't even show at all. Mouse coordinates appear to be off in that clicking certain controls no longer invokes the appropriate actions. It's the strangest thing I've ever seen.

If I close the application and launch a new instance on my desktop, things work great. Also, it only seems to happen when I launch the feature on my laptop, then move to the desktop. Never the other way around.

I wish I could show some code, but I don't really even know where to start or what to show. I can say that it only happens on certain features. Some features handle the resolution change perfectly.

Has anyone else seen these types of symptoms? Or know what could cause them or how they could be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little embarrassing. After a few hours of "process of elimination", I found that another developer had added some unmanaged code to automatically maximize the window. The approach they followed is documented [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/08/01/maximizing-window-_2800_with-windowstyle_3d00_none_2900_-considering-taskbar.aspx). This approach does not work through remote desktop sessions. Lol.

Comment: It happens. Whenever something strange happens I start CTRL+Fing for "DllImport".